# I need some help modifying a url going through an apache Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I inherited this system from my retired coworker who inherited it from the person who set it up, so my knowledge of reverse proxies is pretty bad. Here is the situation...

We are upgrading a system from an older version to a new version. I want to change the url that points to the old system so that we can hide it from users but other admins are still able to access it. It is set up with a reverse proxy server that sends all requests to another web server. Also, there is a shibboleth authentication that takes place.

Here is the config for it...

```
<Location /ABC/>
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
 AuthType shibboleth
 ShibCompatWith24 On
 ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
 ShibRequestSetting forceAuthn 1
 ShibUseHeaders On
 require shib-session

 ProxyPass http://servername:8080/ABC/
 ProxyPassReverse http://servername:8080/ABC/

 </Location>
```

Normally, I would enter https://proxyname/ABC/WebApp and that would take me to the WebApp login.  What I want is to change the location config in the proxy so that https://proxyname/DEF/WebApp will still send the request to the backend web server as https://servername/ABC/WebApp and appear to the user as https://proxyname/DEF/WebApp

I tried this but i'm getting redirected to the wrong url and the backed webserver doesn't know what to do...

```
<Location /DEF/ABC/>
(all the above shib stuff)

ProxyPass http://servername:8080/ABC/
ProxyPassReverse http://servername:8080/ABC/
</Location>
```

I also tried...

```
<Location /DEF/>
(all the above shib stuff)
ProxyPass http://servername:8080/ABC/
ProxyPassReverse http://servername:8080/ABC/
</Location>
```

But that doesn't send the correct url to the backend webserver.  Should I be using something else to make this work?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: Questions about [advanced server administration](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are really best asked over at Server Fault, where it appears you already have [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1120473/i-need-some-help-modifying-a-url-going-through-an-apache-reverse-proxy).

Comment: In the future, please don't [cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-que) to multiple Stack Exchange sites - pick one and then flag it for migration if you think it will better fit on another site.

Comment: Noted...sorry about that!